# <Shrilling> Vs <Piercing>

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I wonder how do the two adjectives [shrilling](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/shrill) and [piercing](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/piercing) differ in meaning when they refer to someone's voice or sound? For instance, how the examples #1 and #2 differ in meaning:

> 1.a- He has a **shrilling** voice. 
>   1.b- He has a **piercing** voice.

or

> 2.a- The noise from the neighbor's house is very **shrilling**. 
>   2.b- The noise from the neighbor's house is very **piercing**.

Additionally, is there any difference between them if a voice or sound is unpleasantly **high**-pitched or **low**-pitched?

Answer (score 2):

**Piercing** simply means that the noise penetrates, but does not *specifically* relate to pitch. **Shrill** means that the noise is particularly high-pitched, but does not *specifically* relate to the penetrating effect. That said, high-pitched noises do tend to be more penetrating, so the two words are in many cases interchangeable.

The appropriateness of the two words in the two examples you provide would depend on whether you want to emphasise the penetrating effect or the pitch of the respective noises.

Note that in British English, we do not use **shrill** as a verb, only an adjective, so there is no participle **shrilling**. Merriam-Webster suggests that **shrill** as a verb is mainly used in southern USA.

Comment: @A-friend: rumbling or booming.

Comment: What about "strident" @JavaLatte?

Comment: @A-friend strident is loud and unpleasant. It's probably more indicative of the person's attitude than anything in particular to do with the type of noise that the person's voice makes.

Comment: I see @JavaLatte. Just, what would you call some harsh songs by Ramsstein in black metal or some e.g. "Dream Evil" songs like a song called "The Story Of Heavy Metal"? (How would you address the sound of instruments or the singer's voice.) Do they sound **strident** to you (supposing that you like country music and some love songs by Elvis or  Johny Cash and so on) you would call them something else? I wonder how do these types of voices and musical instruments' sounds are defined to you?

Comment: My first experience of  Rammstein was that it was the musical choice of the tattooist that put the fish on my leg. I think I will always associate Rammstein with pain. As i said, strident is more about attitude.. emotional content... than tonal quality: think Alanis Morissette's "Right through you". If you were into country music wanted to describe a genre of music that you didn't like, you would probably use the word **cacophonous**.

Comment: Well,interesting information @JavaLatte, but what exactly do you mean by emotional content? Do you mean a sad song (just according to its lyrics, not the instruments and the music) is a strident music? Or let's say a social rap which is nothing special with its music, but it contains lots of painful and deep words regarding a society. Would you call them "strident" or I'm mistaken?

Comment: @A-friend: (sigh). Strident means loud and unpleasant. What emotions would you receive from somebody who is being loud and unpleasant? Strident is not about the lyrics, it's about the way that they are delivered.